# From one argument make two - at compile time

Tags: c++, printf, c++20, constexpr, string-view

I'm writing a special print function that produces a cstdio printf - statement at compile time. The idea is basically that you invoke a function `special_print()` with a variadic parameter list and the function will assemble the necessary printf - statement at compile time. Here's what I've got:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string_view>

// how to implement "expand" from below?

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr const char* cxpr_format = /* ... this one I've already figured out */

template <typename... Ts>
void special_print(Ts... arg)
{
    printf(cxpr_format<Ts...>, expand(arg)...);

    // should expand to printf("%.*s%d", string_view.size(), string_view.data(), int) with below function call
}

int main()
{
    std::string_view strview = "hello world";
    int integer = 2;

    special_print(strview, integer);
}
```

I've already figured out the part for creating my format string - that one is out of the question. But now comes the problem: In case when I've got a `string_view` passed in as an argument, I would need to conditionally expand it to two arguments to printf: one for the initial char pointer and one for the size which goes together with the %.*s format specifier. And this is the real crux. Can this be done somehow in C++ (at compile time)?

**Note**: Before any further questions arise I would like to point out that I have no idea on how to do this in C++ and this is my question. Every approach will be gladly taken into account!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes sorry, but no I have nothing. I have no clue how to implement this, this is just a setup I quickly wrote. But I really don't have anything for the expand - part.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Well... I'm asking for that :D I don't know how to do it that's the point. Or what would you like to see?

Comment: @PasserBy I would very much like to do so, but iostream is too big of an overhead on performance and code bloat and I try to minimize that because I'm running this on an embedded system.

Comment: Since you tagged it C++20, why not use [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)?

Comment: @G.Sliepen Because of the string return type as I don't use dynamic allocation. Also, with std::format I would have the same problems of expanding the arguments.

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee `printf()` won't dynamically allocate. In C++23 we will probably get `std::print()`, which might alleviate your worries? You could also do `((std::cout << arg), ...)`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen That is right but is there any other way? I guess cstdio still has less overhead than iostream hence I'm going old school.

Comment: Don't guess, measure :) `std::cout` might suffer by default from being synced to `stdout`, you might want to call [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) first. The [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) on which `std::format()` is based, is faster than `printf()`, see these [benchmarks](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt#Benchmarks). Of course it depends on exactly what you are printing, so YMMV.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thanks for the input! fmt looks interesting in fact, I might give it another look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My initial thought is to forward each arg through a tuple, and then "varags apply" in the call.

```
template <typename T>
auto expand(T&& t) { return std::forward_as_tuple<T>(t); }

auto expand(std::string_view s) { return std::tuple<int, const char *>(s.size(), s.data()); }

template <typename... Ts>
void special_print(Ts... arg)
{
    using expanded = decltype(std::tuple_cat(expand(arg)...));

    []<std::size_t... Is>(auto tup, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        printf(cxpr_format<Ts...>, std::forward<std::tuple_element_t<Is, expanded>>(std::get<Is>(tup))...);
    }(std::tuple_cat(expand(arg)...), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<expanded>>{});

    // should expand to printf("%.*s%d", string_view.size(), string_view.data(), int) with below function call
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffcfb4543aa3eb47)

Comment: It works perfectly thank you! Now you have two answers, The second one gives me a huge binary for whatever reason (?), so I'm tending to this custom made one. But I feel that format_to would be more idiomatic!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use `printf`, which only knows about types shared with C, you can use the `std::format` library.

```
struct putchar_iterator {
    using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = void;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = void;
    using reference = void;

    putchar_iterator& operator=(char c) { 
        eof = (putchar(c) == EOF);
        return *this; 
    }
    constexpr putchar_iterator& operator*() { return *this; }
    constexpr putchar_iterator& operator++() { return *this; }
    constexpr putchar_iterator& operator++(int) { return *this; }

    friend bool operator==(putchar_iterator lhs, std::default_sentinel_t) { return lhs.eof; }
private:
    bool eof = false;
};

template <typename... Ts>
void special_print(Ts... arg)
{
    // You might be able to std::format_to, but I'm not sure
    std::vformat_to(putchar_iterator{}, cxpr_format<Ts...>, std::make_format_args(arg...));
}
```

[See it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PbT5bvhMG)